# Python Speech Recognition does not recognize my voice

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Always Traceback. I know for sure my mic is working because I am using it to search something in search google via voice.

here is my code.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

rec=sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    rec.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=5)
   
    print("Speak Now: ")
    audio= rec.listen(source)
    try:
        text = rec.recognize_google(audio)
        print(text)
    except:
        print("sorry, could not hear your voice")
```

whenever I run, it always stuck on "please speak now" display and then display this traceback

```
speak now:
sorry, could not hear your voice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\MARTIN\Documents\Learning Python\sr\sr\sr.py", line 14, in <module>
    print("sorry, could not hear your voice")
  File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 1260, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.SafeCallWrapper.__call__
  File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 344, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.PyDBFrame.trace_exception
  File "_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.pyx", line 231, in _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython.is_unhandled_exception
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_collect_bytecode_info.py", line 167, in collect_try_except_info
    def collect_try_except_info(co, use_func_first_line=False):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please someone help me fix this. Thanks in advance, I am beginner in speech recognition of python.

Comment: Using your code I get expected behaviour - recognises and then prints out whatever I say, or if I say nothing returns an appropriate exception. So the problem is not the code - but perhaps your installation of python or the library/module. How did you install speech recognition? Have you tried running this from an interactive instance of python?

Comment: I am using pyaudio. Yes I tried however, It would just stuck on 'speak now' print method and then I have to quit the shell in order to stop the program.

Comment: I installed the pyaudio using .whl via cmd.